# Why does RestSharp throw "Method not found" Inner Exception?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm creating a very simple RestRequest using RestSharp.

`var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, Method.Post);`

And the add a StringBody with my Json payload:

`request.AddStringBody(serealized_payload, RestSharp.DataFormat.Json);`

My app is built using .NET Framework 4.8 and there are no other libraries installed that depend on RestSharp.

However, when I try to run my application, it throws an Inner Exception:

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: "RestSharp.RestRequest RestSharp.RestRequestExtensions.AddStringBody(RestSharp.RestRequest, System.String, RestSharp.DataFormat)".

I did read through the other threads like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678696/method-not-found-restsharp-irestreuqest-restsharp-restrequest-addfile), where the issue was usually resolved by fixing RestSharp dependencies. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue (Auto-generate binding redirects in VS 2022 is turned on). I also tried recreating the issue in a console application, where I installed all packages I use in my main app. It worked like a charm there, no problems...

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try using request.AddParameter?

Comment: .AddParameter(Parameter parameter) seems not to throw the error. 
Parameter.CreateParameter() does, though. And so do all overloads of .AddParameter(). Could it have anything to do with the extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to pinpoint the problem. Another program running a plug-in in the same software as mine used an older version of the assembly, which was loaded first, thus the runtime error. Using a local reference instead of installing RestSharp through NuGet solved the issue for me.